# Converting a year period in minutes to months in matplotlib ticks

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, matplotlib

I'm making a project at the moment which involves data that needs to be converted to certain timestamps. I have a python list of 364 days in minutes so 364*1440 = 518400 indexes. I tried to use the xticks command but how to convert the amount of minutes to a month on the x-axis? This is my code:

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import numpy as np

 grid = []

 plt.figure()
 plt.ylabel('Power in W')
 plt.xlabel('Time in minutes')
 plt.title('Grid Powergraph')
 plt.xticks(np.linspace(0, 524160, 12))
 plt.grid(True)
 plt.plot(grid)
 plt.show()
```

[The following graph is generated by the code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaWSK.png)

How can I convert the x-axis to months instead of just minutes.

Answer (score -1):

Try this small change:

```
plt.xticks(np.linspace(0, 524160, 12), np.arange(1, 13))
```

`matplotlib.pyplot.xticks()` has an argument for providing specific labels to the xticks. [Check out the `labels` argument in the matplotlib documentation page.](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Its not just as easy as dividing the total x-axis by 12. Every month has another amount of days. My aim is also to make multiple timestamps in weeks, days and hours so this isn't the right solution. Thank you for helping though.